# How to get the SharePoint authenticated user from an ASP.NET webpage?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, authentication, active-directory, single-sign-on

I am kind of new to this, and I'm still trying to figure out how the whole thing works.

I have a sharepoint site, and I also have separate ASP webpages, they are under the same domain, but different servers. They both authenticate to AD.

I thought that by having my webpages under the same domain as the sharepoint, once I had an user authenticate to sharepoint (windows authentication), my webpages would be able to find who that was, as long as they had windows authentication also. But I guess it doesn't work like that.

So, my main goal is: from an ASP.NET page, I want to be able to get the authentication info from SharePoint.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Based on your comments below you need to be asking about the SunGaurd portal, possible at their own support site, and not generic ASP.NET pages.

Answer (score 1):

The users are authenticated by thier login credentials with AD. In a C# ASP.Net page you can get thier username from `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

You can use this information to make a web service call to the [SharePoint User Profile Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms550407.aspx) in order to get details SharePoint records on that user. This assumes that the user profile services is installed and running (not a given).

As for authentication information, you will need to be more specific about which information.
Remember that the rights given to a given AD user differ completely between what is permissioned for SharePoint and anything you have for the ASP.Net website.

If you are wanting to get information on what permissions a given user has, you can use the [SharePoint Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/permissions.permissions_members%28v=office.12%29.aspx) web service to get information on what permission there are.
Unfortunately, accessing that webservice requires elevated rights on the SharePoint server.

If you are just wanting to align the two sites so they have consistent permissions, your easiest bet is to create the relevant groups in AD and permission those groups independantly in each application.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. As far as being more specific, sorry about that, basicaly what I'm looking for is one single authentication for both sites, so if I log in to a SharePoint site, I don't want to be challenged again when going to the ASP page.

Comment: Is this more like what you want? http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.co.nz/2008/06/how-do-i-make-our-sharepoint-site-stop.html

Comment: I think it is more likely that I don't have things set up properly. Perhaps my question is... what does it take to have authentication transparent between sharepoint and an external asp.net page?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what sort of things you would expect from transparent authentication between SharePoint and the external site?

Comment: I want the user to log in to the SharePoint Portal and then not have to log in again when getting to the external website. Actually this Portal is a package from SunGard, and I am supposed to find out how to integrate our web applications to SunGard's portal authentication so that we have a single sign on. I followed all steps (setting up directory security and so on) but I can't get it working. I'm not quite sure where to go.